# How to make a file chooser that preserve as an object some data?

Tags: python, python-2.7, object, user-interface

I would like to read a .txt file and then apply some pre-processing with scikit-learn, for example assume that i want to vectorize (i.e. make a vector representation from some text) some text i tried with this script but i can´t apply such pre-processing to the selected file(.txt), which is in the desktop.

This is what i done:

```
# -- coding: utf-8 --
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer


vectorizer= CountVectorizer(min_df=1)

Tk().withdraw
opinion_filename = askopenfilename()


opinion_filename = askopenfilename()
if opinion_filename:
    with open(opinion_filename) as opinion_file:
        X = vectorizer.fit_transform(opinion_file)
        print("This is the name of the filename:",opinion_filename)
        print ("This is the vectorized filename ",X)
else:
   # user might select no file and hit cancel the file open dialog
   pass
```

This is the output:

```
('This is the name of the filename:', '/Users/user/Desktop/opinion_prueba.txt')
('This is the vectorized filename ', <1x22 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 22 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>)
```

I would like to return the vector representation of the .txt file.

Answer (score 0):

The method `askopenfilename` returns the name of the file (as a string), not a file object that you could read data from. So you need to update your code to open a file object from the file name, and then pass that file object to `vectorizer.fit_transform`.

```
opinion_filename = askopenfilename()
if opinion_filename:
    with open(opinion_filename) as opinion_file:
        X = vectorizer.fit_transform(opinion_file)
        # rest of the code ...
else:
   # user might select no file and hit cancel the file open dialog
   pass
```

Comment: That´s the problem, i need the content of the file, not the name, i'll pass very large .text files, does this works with large files?.

Comment: It depends on how `vectorizer.fit_transform` method (from sklearn) is going to read the file. If it reads the whole file at once, it would need to load all the contents to memory. But I think since it accepts an iterator/file object it is designed to read chunk by chunk or line by line. when we use `with open(filename) as fileobj` we just return a file object that iterates over the file contents, no data is read yet. So I guess there should be no problem with large files. I suggest to test your app with a large file to see the behavior.